# FPDF com MySQL e PHP - Trazendo dados repetidos

Tags: php, array, query, while, fpdf

Estou tentando montar um sistema gerador de `Vouchers/Tickets`

Tenho uma tabela em *SQL* com o nome *Vouchers* com vários usuários e suas respectivas senhas.

Chamo em cada *cell* a variável `$serial_voucher` e `$senha_voucher`

Porém ele só mostra a primeira linha e aplica em todas as *Cell*.

Obrigado, fico agradecido se alguém conseguir me dar essa força.

[image: DADOS REPETIDOS]

```
 <?php 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,'voucherss');

            $query=mysqli_query($con,"select *from vouchers");
            while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

//A4 WIDTH : 219MM


require ('pdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new Fpdf ('p','mm','A4');

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image("imagemfundo.jpg", 0,0,210,295);


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','','8');


$pdf->SetY( 20.3 );///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );   ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['serial_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 1

$pdf->SetY( 28.1);///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );   ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['senha_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 1



$pdf->SetY( 20.3);///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 177.8 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['serial_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );    /////DIREITA 1

$pdf->SetY( 28.4); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 177.8 ); ///LADOS 

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['senha_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );     /////DIREITA 1


$pdf->SetY( 78.8 ); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['serial_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 2

$pdf->SetY( 86.3); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['senha_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 2



$pdf->SetY( 78.5); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 178 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['serial_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );    /////DIREITA 2

$pdf->SetY( 86.3);///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 178 ); ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['senha_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );     /////DIREITA 2    



$pdf->SetY( 136.5);///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );   ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['serial_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 3

$pdf->SetY( 144.3);///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );   ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['senha_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 3



$pdf->SetY( 136.5);///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 177.8 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['serial_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );    /////DIREITA 3

$pdf->SetY( 144.4); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 177.8 ); ///LADOS 

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['senha_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );     /////DIREITA 3




$pdf->SetY( 194.8 ); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['serial_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 4

$pdf->SetY( 202.7); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['senha_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 4



$pdf->SetY( 194.8); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 178 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['serial_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );    /////DIREITA 4

$pdf->SetY( 202.7);///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 178 ); ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['senha_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );     /////DIREITA 4




$pdf->SetY( 252.8 ); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['serial_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 5

$pdf->SetY( 260.6); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 74 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell(0,10,$data['senha_voucher'],0,0,'L');   /////ESQUERDA 5



$pdf->SetY( 252.8); ///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 178 );  ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['serial_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );    /////DIREITA 5

$pdf->SetY( 260.6);///PRA CIMA OU PRA BAIXO
$pdf->SetX( 178 ); ///LADOS

    $pdf->Cell( 0,10, $data['senha_voucher'], 0, 0, '' );     /////DIREITA 5        





$pdf->Output();



    }?>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo, te recomendo a fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), sanando seu problema, isso esta ocorrendo porque está dentro do laço de repetição `while`, coloque fora do laço aquilo que não é para ser repetido, tipo dados que são inseridos manualmente por você. `require ('pdf/fpdf.php');` não era pra estar dentro do laço.

Comment: Certo, consegui compreender, já fiz alguns outros pequenos sistemas onde trabalhei com as colunas do HTML, lá bastava eu inserir o While com o <tr></tr> e seus <td><?php echo $rows['id'];?></td>  e pronto.
- Porém neste caso, necessito configurar a posição de cada Cell no FPDF para encaixar exatamente no Input do template.pdf por esse motivo estou repetindo a variável em cada Cell.  acredito que o problema está aí, mas de que outra maneira poderia fazer?

Comment: Quais os dados que não é para repetir? Coloque essa linha `$pdf = new Fpdf ('p','mm','A4');` e essa também `$pdf->Output();` para fora do `while`

Comment: Exemplo.
Tenho uma tabela  com as colunas Serial e senha.
Usuario 1  | Senha1
Usuario 2 | Senha 2
E assim sucessivamente, porém por algum erro no código está trazendo apenas a primeira linha,  Usuario 1 | Senha 1, sendo que em cada voucher deveria ir um usuário e senha diferente.
Está mostrando os dados corretos porém quero que mostre todos e não só a primeira linha.

Comment: Você quer os dados em um *PDF* só ? Se não, apenas coloque as linhas `require ('pdf/fpdf.php'); $pdf = new Fpdf ('p','mm','A4');` antes do `while` e a linha `$pdf->Output();` depois do `while`.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza olha, com a sua sugestão agora parece que está melhorando, agora está escrevendo dados diferentes porém em cada página, exemplo  Pagina 1    Usuário 1 | Senha 1 e se repete até a próxima pagina... Pagina 2. Usuário 2 | Senha 2 e se repete também.
Resumindo: Está listando todos os dados do banco porém em uma página para cada usuário.

Comment: Coloque o `$pdf->Output();` dentro do `while` novamente para ver se ajuda. Não tem como eu testar agora se não falaria exato para você.

Comment: Fiz como você sugeriu, mas voltamos ao ponto 0 hehe. Não funcionou.

Comment: Ok, tira novamente, coloque também antes do `while` a linha `$pdf->AddPage();` pois é ela que adiciona nova pagina, agora vejo que você esta chamando varias vezes `$pdf->SetY` e `$pdf->SetX`, o laço e percorre linha por linha do resultado retornado, então se você repetir esses métodos da classe *FPDF* dentro do laço apenas vai repetir os dados da linha atual e não da próxima, para que funcione você devera criar condições, algo [assim](https://repl.it/OI3K/0) dai vai fazendo a soma para posicionar os objetos.

Comment: Blz, segui suas orientações e outros tutoriais na internet como estes http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script30.php  http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php
Segue como está meu código atualmente.

https://repl.it/repls/UnwittingOverjoyedKentrosaurus
Por enquanto, imprimindo os dados só no primeiro cartão de cada página, além disso está repetindo a mesma informação do lado direito e esquerdo.
desespero batendo rsrsrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dei uma mexida em  seu código mais creio que esta no resultado que espera, bastando apenas fazer as alterações conforme sua necessidade, creio que possa ter jeitos mais fáceis de obter o resultado. Abaixo o código funcionando:

```
require ('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,'voucherss');

$pdf = new Fpdf ('p','mm','A4');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','','16');
$pdf->AddPage();

//////INICIA COM ESSAS DIMENSOES
$yincrementasenha = 28.5;
$yincrementaserial = 20.3;

$linhas = 6; // Máximo de linhas por página
$coluna = 1; // Contagem de colunas
$count_lines = 0; // Contagem de linhas na página

$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from vouchers");

while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $serial = $data['serial_voucher'];
    $senha = $data['senha_voucher'];

    if ($coluna === 1){
        $pdf->SetY( $yincrementaserial ); # Define a posião para Cima ou para Baixo
        $pdf->Cell(95,10, $serial,0,0,'L'); # Conteúdo do lado Esquerdo
        $pdf->SetY( $yincrementasenha ); # Define a posião para Cima ou para Baixo
        $pdf->Cell(95,10, $senha,0,0,'L'); # Conteúdo do lado Esquerdo
        $coluna++; // Faz incremento na contagem de colunas
    } elseif ($coluna === 2) {
        $count_lines++; // Faz incremento na contagem de linhas
        $pdf->SetY( $yincrementaserial ); # Define a posião para Cima ou para Baixo
        $pdf->SetX( 110 ); # Define a posição para Esquerda ou para Direita
        $pdf->Cell(95,10, $serial,0,0,'L'); # Conteúdo do lado Direito
        $pdf->SetY( $yincrementasenha ); # Define a posião para Cima ou para Baixo
        $pdf->SetX( 110 ); # Define a posição para Esquerda ou para Direita
        $pdf->Cell(95,10, $senha,0,0,'L'); # Conteúdo do lado Direito
        $coluna = 1; //  Reset a contagem de colunas
        $yincrementaserial = $yincrementaserial+24.4;
        $yincrementasenha = $yincrementasenha+24.4;
    }
    /*
     * Condição para verifcar se o números de linhas na página atual
     * é maior que cinco, se for adiciona nova página e reset as variáveis
     */
    if ($count_lines > 5){
        $pdf->AddPage(); // Adiciona nova página
        // Reset as variáveis para seus valores iniciais
        $count_lines = 0;
        $yincrementasenha = 28.5;
        $yincrementaserial = 20.3;
    }
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Algumas *screens* do código funcionando:

[image: Exemplo funcionando: Página 1]
[image: Exemplo funcionando: Página 2]

Comment: Cara, muito bom. Obrigado pela ajuda, teve uma alteração que precisei fazer em seu código além das minhas personalizações, na parte de adicionar a página tem que ser > 4 e não 5. Quando estava pulando pra próxima página não adicionava a seguinte Row, exemplo : 5 pulava pro 7 Mas continuo com o problema incial, o Script continua apenas clonando a coluna esquerda, preciso que as informações sejam diferentes em cada coluna, cada voucher com serial diferente. COLUNA 1 : SERIAL1 SERIAL3 | COLUNA 2 : SERIAL2 SERIAL4
Achei um pessoal discutindo sobre isso (https://goo.gl/kqADqV)

Comment: @MichelTeixeira, desculpe foi um erro meu, vou atualizar a resposta, pois na hora que eu estava testando estava certo, mais quando fui colocar aqui fiz uma alteração e não tinha percebido que estava colocando a coluna da direita igual da esquerda. O problema estava na condição *if* no qual eu não estava fazendo o *elseif*.

Comment: Já verifiquei e agora sim, está no perfeito estado da arte! Muito Obrigado.

Comment: já estou com o script bem avançado, muito obrigado pela sua primeira ajuda, gostaria que me ajudasse com mais uma coisa. 
Com o código que você criou, estou tendo uma problema.. No momento de exibir por exemplo 50 vouchers, na lógica seriam 5 páginas. Porém na quinta página os últimos dois vouchers ficam vazios, fiz uma edição no código e consegui deixar tudo preenchido, porém está adicionando uma pagina a mais, em branco. 
Help! :(

Comment: @MichelTeixeira por essa pergunta aqui não poderei ajudar, recomendo [fazer uma nova pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) e lá verificamos o que está acontecendo, coloque na nova pergunta o link para essa resposta.

Comment: Beleza, obrigado pela info, criei a pergunta aqui >>> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256667/fpdf-com-php-ultima-p%C3%A1gina-em-branco