# FPDF com php ultima página em branco

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

Estou com um probleminha em meu código, ele está gerando a última página em branco.

Acompanhe a criação deste código com a ajuda da comunidade: [FPDF com MySQL e PHP - Trazendo dados repetidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254907/60376)

Já alterei as variáveis, mas sem sucesso.

```
$my_serial =["SERIAL1","SERIAL2","SERIAL3","SERIAL4","SERIAL5","SERIAL6","SERIAL7","SERIAL8","SERIAL9","SERIAL10","SERIAL11","SERIAL12","SERIAL13","SERIAL14","SERIAL15","SERIAL16","SERIAL17","SERIAL18","SERIAL19","SERIAL20","SERIAL1","SERIAL2","SERIAL3","SERIAL4","SERIAL5","SERIAL6","SERIAL7","SERIAL8","SERIAL9","SERIAL10","SERIAL11","SERIAL12","SERIAL13","SERIAL14","SERIAL15","SERIAL16","SERIAL17","SERIAL18","SERIAL19","SERIAL20","SERIAL21","SERIAL22","SERIAL23","SERIAL24","SERIAL25","SERIAL26","SERIAL27","SERIAL28","SERIAL29","SERIAL30","SERIAL31","SERIAL32","SERIAL33","SERIAL34","SERIAL35","SERIAL36","SERIAL37","SERIAL38","SERIAL39","SERIAL40","SERIAL41","SERIAL42","SERIAL43","SERIAL44","SERIAL45","SERIAL46","SERIAL47","SERIAL48","SERIAL49","SERIAL50","SERIAL51","SERIAL52","SERIAL53","SERIAL54","SERIAL55","SERIAL56","SERIAL57","SERIAL58","SERIAL59","SERIAL60","SERIAL61","SERIAL62","SERIAL63","SERIAL64","SERIAL65","SERIAL66","SERIAL67","SERIAL68","SERIAL69","SERIAL70"];               ///  randomSerial(6,20,"lower_case,numbers");
$my_passwords =["SERIAL1","SERIAL2","SERIAL3","SERIAL4","SERIAL5","SERIAL6","SERIAL7","SERIAL8","SERIAL9","SERIAL10","SERIAL11","SERIAL12","SERIAL13","SERIAL14","SERIAL15","SERIAL16","SERIAL17","SERIAL18","SERIAL19","SERIAL20","SERIAL1","SERIAL2","SERIAL3","SERIAL4","SERIAL5","SERIAL6","SERIAL7","SERIAL8","SERIAL9","SERIAL10","SERIAL11","SERIAL12","SERIAL13","SERIAL14","SERIAL15","SERIAL16","SERIAL17","SERIAL18","SERIAL19","SERIAL20","SERIAL21","SERIAL22","SERIAL23","SERIAL24","SERIAL25","SERIAL26","SERIAL27","SERIAL28","SERIAL29","SERIAL30","SERIAL31","SERIAL32","SERIAL33","SERIAL34","SERIAL35","SERIAL36","SERIAL37","SERIAL38","SERIAL39","SERIAL40","SERIAL41","SERIAL42","SERIAL43","SERIAL44","SERIAL45","SERIAL46","SERIAL47","SERIAL48","SERIAL49","SERIAL50","SERIAL51","SERIAL52","SERIAL53","SERIAL54","SERIAL55","SERIAL56","SERIAL57","SERIAL58","SERIAL59","SERIAL60","SERIAL61","SERIAL62","SERIAL63","SERIAL64","SERIAL65","SERIAL66","SERIAL67","SERIAL68","SERIAL69","SERIAL70"];                      ///randomPassword(5,20,"lower_case,numbers");



//////INICIA COM ESSAS DIMENSOES
$yincrementasenha = 28.5;
$yincrementaserial = 20.3;
$Xrepetedireita = 177.8;
$Xrepeteesquerda = 74;

$linhas = 0; // Máximo de linhas por página
$coluna = 1; // Contagem de colunas
$count_lines = 0; // Contagem de linhas na página
$linha1= 0;
$linha2= 0;
$total=0;







    foreach (array_combine($my_serial, $my_passwords) as $serial2 => $dae1) {


    if ($coluna === 1){
        $pdf->SetY( $yincrementaserial ); # Define a posião para Cima ou para Baixo
         $pdf->SetX($Xrepeteesquerda);
        $pdf->Cell(150,10, $serial2,0,0); # Conteúdo do lado Esquerdo
        $pdf->SetY( $yincrementasenha ); # Define a posião para Cima ou para Baixo
           $pdf->SetX($Xrepeteesquerda);
        $pdf->Cell(150,10, $dae1,0,0); # Conteúdo do lado Esquerdo
        $coluna++; // Faz incremento na contagem de colunas[]
        $linha1++;

    }
   elseif ($coluna === 2) {

        $pdf->SetX($Xrepetedireita);
         // Faz incremento na contagem de linhas
        $pdf->SetY( $yincrementaserial ); # Define a posião para Cima ou para Baixo
        $pdf->SetX($Xrepetedireita); # Define a posição para Esquerda ou para Direita
        $pdf->Cell(0,10, $serial2,0,0); # Conteúdo do lado Direito
        $pdf->SetY( $yincrementasenha ); # Define a posião para Cima ou para Baixo
        $pdf->SetX($Xrepetedireita); # Define a posição para Esquerda ou para Direita
        $pdf->Cell(0,10, $dae1,0,0); # Conteúdo do lado Direito
        $coluna = 1; //  Reset a contagem de colunas
        $yincrementaserial = $yincrementaserial+58;
        $yincrementasenha = $yincrementasenha+58;
        $linha2++;
        $total++;  
    }
    /*
     * Condição para verifcar se o números de linhas na página atual
     * é maior que cinco, se for adiciona nova página e reset as variáveis
     */
    if ($linha1 && $linha2 > 4){

        $pdf->AddPage(); // Adiciona nova página
        // Reset as variáveis para seus valores iniciais
        $pdf->Image("imagemfundo.jpg", 0,0,210,295);
        $count_lines = 0;
        $linha2=0;
        $linha1=0;
        $total=$linha1;
        $yincrementasenha = 28.5;
        $yincrementaserial = 20.3;
    }

}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Quando respondi a outra pergunta eu criei a variável `$linhas = 5;` e se olhar vai perceber que ela não é utilizada, mas defina o valor dela como zero, `$linhas = 0;`, dentro do *while* e depois da condição acrescente a linha `$linhas++;`, crie uma nova variável antes do `while` e guarde nela o número de registros retornados pelo método `mysqli_query` ex: `$registros = mysqli_num_rows($query);`

Comment: Altere a condição para `if ($count_lines > 5 && $linhas < $registros)`, obs.: **Não tem como eu testar no momento**.

Comment: Fiz conforme suas orientações, mas sem sucesso. solicitei 100 vouchers, foram geradas 10 páginas porém a última vem com 2 vouchers em branco.

Comment: Ficou faltando eu adicionar o $linhas++ dentro do While, fiz a correção.. porém agora ao invés de aparecer 10 paginas aparecem apenas 5 páginas, como se estivesse contando cada vez que passa por uma coluna... ou seja, dividindo por dois.

Comment: Funcionou pra vc @wmsouza?

Comment: Eu estava verificando o código agora, e engraçado que eu crie uma tabela para simular a sua, e inseri 101 registros nelas que no total da 11 páginas, e pra mim está normal. A unica coisa que alterei ai, foi como eu disse no primeiro comentário, que não estava utilizando a variável `$linha`, deixe ele como está antes do comentário e altere só a condição deixando assim: `if ($count_lines >= $linhas)`

Comment: Ainda não, fiz conforme seu primeiro comentário, depois fiz conforme o segundo alterando só o `if ($count_lines >= $linhas)` mas passou a exibir só uma página. voltei ao código original, onde continua deixando os últimos dois vouchers em branco... sei lá porque

Comment: Fiz alteração do código na minha pergunta, nesse modo está deixando os últimos dois vouchers em branco, fiz suas sugestões mas não funfou.

Comment: Veja que dentro do condição `if ($count_lines > 5)` a variável `$count_lines` esta recebendo o valor 1 sendo que era pra estar recebendo 0, faça essa alteração e altere a condição para `if ($count_lines >= $linhas)` e altere também `$linhas = 0;` para `$linhas = 3;` que pela imagem da outra pergunta vejo que são três linhas por páginas.

Comment: veja que dei uma atualizada no código, é assim que está agora. Array com 70 códigos, gerando 8 páginas, dessa maneira fica sobrando uma página inteira, ah e no if coloco > 4 porque assim consegui o melhor resultado, quando adiciono o > 5 adiciona apenas 6 páginas, porém a cada salto de página ele fica sem 2 vouchers, exemplo do voucher 10 ele pula pro 13, dai altera tudo, onde era pra terminar com 20 termina em 22, do 22 pula pro 25.